# parsing input from a String in Java

Tags: java, regex, parsing, split

I have a String add as **Phenix City, AL 36867**.
I want to eventually have 3 java Strings: city, state, zip corresponding to the values.

What I have kind of works but is very complicated.  Split the string by a comma

```
String[] halves = add.split(",");
String city = halves[0].replace(",","").trim();
```

and then screw around with the remainder

```
String remainder = halves[1].trim();
String[] fields = remainder.split("");
String state = fields[0];
String zip = fields[1];
```

but it seems like there must be a more elegant way?

Answer (score 7):

Just split according to the below regex.

```
string.split("\\s*,\\s*|\\s+(?=\\d)");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iG6fF2/1)

Answer (score 0):

Alternately with regex:

```
^(.*), ([A-Z][A-Z]) (\d{5})
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kW6hO9/1)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this :

```
static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\s*([\\w\\s]+),\\s*([A-Z]+)\\s*(\\d{5})\\s*");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Phenix City, AL 36867";
    Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(input);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1).trim()); // City
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); // State
        System.out.println(matcher.group(3)); // Zip
    }
}
```